# Ionic 2 file uploading not working. How to create File upload in ionic2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

**My ionic info**

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.3
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.8
Node Version: v6.10.1
Xcode version: Not installed
```

I am using ionic 2, I trying to create **file upload** on my app but that is not working. How to solve this problem?
How can I create using **native plugin** or **angular2** file upload?
which one is the best way and give some sample codes.

Comment: Use this https://github.com/babarxm/ng-uploader

Comment: Hi @BabarBilal thank you for your replay.  i use this link and i am getting error? if any working code ?

Comment: what error it is a lib install it and use it for upload